# Create db connection as a class and use in prepare statement in PHP and Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I tried to create the database connection as a class.

DB.class.php

```
class DB {

protected $servername = 'localhost';
protected $username = 'root';
protected $password = '';
protected $dbname = 'my_db';
protected $conn ;

public function connection(){

    $connection = new mysqli($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'db error'.mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    $this->conn = $connection;
    return $this->conn;
 }
}
```

It seems that there is no any issue with this class. I want to use this class in another file which is query.php

```
include 'DB.class.php';

$connection = new DB();
$connection->connect($connection);

$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, gender, email, 
town) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $gender, $email, $town);

$name = 'ex_name';
$gender = 'female';
$email = 'example@gmail.com';
$town = 'colombo';

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$connection->close();
```

But it keeps showing this error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::connect()
```

Should I create this query inside a class to avoid this error message? If yes how can I do that. Can somebody help me !

Comment: Your DB class has no method name ‘connect’ exactly as the error shows you. You have a method called ‘connection’ which looks like it should return your handle so try $connection=new DB()->connection();

Comment: Why are you trying to connect using and existing connection? Also you realize that every you call `connection()` you're creating a new database connection right? Do this 1k times and you'll notice the time lag and you might kill your server.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to make your own `DB` class? As it doesn't seem to offer any functionalities over the `mysqli` class, you would make it a lot easier on yourself to just use that. Or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

If you see your code, does not exists the method connect, is connection and it has any parameter. Also is wrong because you are passing the same offset to itself.

```
$connection = new DB();
```

The `$connection->connect($connection);` must be `$connection->connection();`

Comment: Then it says "Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare()"

Comment: Ok, because there is not method implemented called prepare. public function prepare($sql){

 return $this->conn($sql);
}

Comment: And is also to fail with close. public function close(){ $this->conn->close()}